# What is difference of occupancy grid map and elevation map

Tags: navigation, robotics, elevation

I want to use occupancy grid  map or elevation map for navigation. what is difference of occupancy grid  map and elevation map in navigation?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of an environment around you [Say a 2D array where the dimensions are your position in x and y] - Lets call this a grid for this concept. This grid becomes a  binary occupancy grid map, if you denote the "value" of each point (i.e an xy coordinate) to be 1 if it is occupied, and 0 if it is not.
These are useful to model obstacles to avoid collisions.
We can make denser and more detailed occupancy maps by adding different features and representations of what we wish to map.

It becomes an elevation map, when the "value" that we spoke about above, indicates the height of the terrain or environment around you.